# WPF ListView remove mouseover effect

Tags: wpf, listview

Hi there im using a ListView in wpf running on a Windows 7 machine, now when i drag the mouse over the listview i get a little blue border around it how do i remove that effect? (im not talking about the rows the whole listview)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can get rid of that effect by making a small change to the `BorderThickness` for the `ListView` (same thing with `TextBox`)

Try this

```
<ListView ...
          BorderThickness="1.000001">
```

Comment: @Petoj: Hehe, I agree :) I tried to research this for a `TextBox` a while back but I never found the reason for why the effect goes away when changing the `BorderThickness`

Comment: An old post, but thanks. Since I don't need a border, I simply use BorderThickness="0"

Answer (score 0):

Its a slippery slope you are going on. Why do you want to remove the 'little blue border around the list view'. I guess its the focus visual and it serves a purpose in the UI. Unless you are going for a completely customized list view style I would suggest leaving it alone.

One way to disable it is to define a type based style for the listview in the application resources (likely in App.xaml)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" /> 
</Style>
```

Comment: Well yes im going for a custom UI, and im sorry to say but this had no effect:(